# Anchor IDL command / verification

Tags: anchor, solana-program, idl

```
> anchor idl
Commands for interacting with interface definitions

Usage: anchor-0.29.0 idl [OPTIONS] <COMMAND>

Commands:
  init             Initializes a program's IDL account. Can only be run once
  close            
  write-buffer     Writes an IDL into a buffer account. This can be used with SetBuffer to perform an upgrade
  set-buffer       Sets a new IDL buffer for the program
  upgrade          Upgrades the IDL to the new file. An alias for first writing and then then setting the idl buffer account
  set-authority    Sets a new authority on the IDL account
  erase-authority  Command to remove the ability to modify the IDL account. This should likely be used in conjection with eliminating an "upgrade authority" on the program
  authority        Outputs the authority for the IDL account
  parse            Parses an IDL from source
  build            Generates the IDL for the program using the compilation method
  fetch            Fetches an IDL for the given address from a cluster. The address can be a program, IDL account, or IDL buffer
  help             Print this message or the help of the given subcommand(s)

Options:
      --provider.cluster <CLUSTER>  Cluster override
      --provider.wallet <WALLET>    Wallet override
  -h, --help                        Print help
```

What does init, close, upgrade, set-authority etc all mean?

Is the IDL an actual account on the solana blockchain? If so, what purpose does it serve? In the course of testing my custom program, I see this IDL command which I'm trying to understand more.